# I'm struggling with loops and returning a specific format for each key

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

*Edited to include sql, desired output vs current and a sample of db info*

I'm not sure I understand loops very well.

I want to display results from a query in a certain format for permit inspections.  For each permit number I want a few pieces of information to display as a header section and then loop through each of the inspection dates and display their info beneath it.  The problem I'm running into is that some addresses have multiple permits due to the age of the property.  With my current code, I pull the data I want and format it correctly, however, it never displays a "new" header section with the next permit number for that address.  It does continue to loop through the rest of the inspection date info through the last row of results.

Using the column names from the table, this is essentially how I want the HTML to be displayed.  Permit information and street address, loop through the various inspection dates, and if the property has another permit, start back over and print that information and then loop through those inspection dates.  What is happening is the first permit information is being displayed, but if the property has more than one permit number, that permit info isn't displayed, but the inspection date info from the loop is:

```
    //What I want it to look like
    //This info displayed once per ['APKEYFULL']
    123 MAIN Permit: F987654
    Inspection Period: 36 Months
    System Type: Leach
    //This information displayed for each inspection date
    Inspection Date:  01-02-2012
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2010
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2008
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    123 MAIN Permit: F456789  //Same address, new permit number
    Inspection Period: 36 Months
    System Type: Leach
    //This information displayed for each inspection date
    Inspection Date:  01-02-2018
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2016
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2014
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.


    //What it actually looks like

    123 MAIN Permit: F987654
    Inspection Period: 36 Months
    System Type: Leach
    //This information displayed for each inspection date
    Inspection Date:  01-02-2012
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2010
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2008
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2018  //Notice no new permit number but the inspection date values display appropriately
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2016
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.

    Inspection Date:  01-02-2014
    Inspection Status: Passed
    Code Violation Status:  Complied
    H1234 AOM Designation
    Keep up the good work.
```

I've tried `foreach` but that loops through all results based on the total number of rows returned from the query which is not what I need.  I've also done nested `while` loops.  This displays correctly everything I need - it just displays it all based on the total number of rows in the query again.  My code probably isn't efficient so my apologies.

Each permit number has a key associated with it.  I thought I could figure out something along the lines of (mix of code and English):

```
    if ($key != $current_permit){
        start at the beginning with the next $key;
    }
```

But I can't seem to figure that out either.

And finally, my actual code and sample db table:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+----------+----------------+
| APKEYFULL | STNOFULL | STNAMEFULL | APNOFULL |  HPERPRD  | HSEPTYP | COMPDTTM | STATTYPE | DESCRIPT478 | FAILED |    DESCRIPT     | COMMENTS255 |   LOC    | COMMENTSFAILED |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+----------+----------------+
|     44444 |      123 | MAIN       | F987654  | 36 months | LEACH   | 1/2/2008 | Passed   | Complied    | H1234  | AOM Designation | Keep up     | the good | work.          |
|     44444 |      123 | MAIN       | F987654  | 36 months | LEACH   | 1/2/2010 | Passed   | Complied    | H1234  | AOM Designation | Keep up     | the good | work.          |
|     44444 |      123 | MAIN       | F987654  | 36 months | LEACH   | 1/2/2012 | Passed   | Complied    | H1234  | AOM Designation | Keep up     | the good | work.          |
|     55555 |      123 | MAIN       | F456789  | 36 months | LEACH   | 1/2/2014 | Passed   | Complied    | H1234  | AOM Designation | Keep up     | the good | work.          |
|     55555 |      123 | MAIN       | F456789  | 36 months | LEACH   | 1/2/2016 | Passed   | Complied    | H1234  | AOM Designation | Keep up     | the good | work.          |
|     55555 |      123 | MAIN       | F456789  | 36 months | LEACH   | 1/2/2018 | Passed   | Complied    | H1234  | AOM Designation | Keep up     | the good | work.          |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+----------+----------------+



    $serverName = "localhost";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydb", "UID"=>"myuser", "PWD"=>"pass", "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if($conn === false) {
        echo "Could not connect.\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $searchstno = $_GET['stnumber'];
    $searchstname = $_GET['stname'];

    $where = "WHERE (LTRIM(STNOFULL) = '$searchstno') AND 
                (STNAMEFULL LIKE '%$searchstname%') AND (WORKTYPE ='SEPBSA' OR  WORKTYPE = 'SEPLN') AND (APBLDGSTAT <> 'V') AND (STAT <> 0) 
                ORDER BY COMPDTTM DESC";
    $query1 ="SELECT  [APKEYFULL]
                      ,[COMMENTS]
                      ,[APNOFULL]
                      ,[APINSPKEY]
                      ,[COMPDTTM]
                      ,[COMMENTSFAILED]
                      ,[FAILED]
                      ,[LOC]
                      ,[LOT]
                      ,[STNOFULL]
                      ,[STNAMEFULL]
                      ,[STSUBFULL]
                      ,[AREA]
                      ,[HSEPTYP]
                      ,[HPERPRD]
                      ,[DESCRIPT]
                      ,[COMMENTS255]
                      ,[WORKTYPE]
                      ,[STAT]
                      ,[WAIVED]
                      ,[APBLDGSTAT]
                      ,[FINDTTM]
                      ,[PARTIAL]
                      ,[DESCRIPT478]
                      ,[HALTECH],
                      CASE WHEN STAT = 0 THEN 'No Action'
                         WHEN STAT = 1 THEN 'Passed'
                         WHEN STAT = 2 THEN 'Failed'
                         WHEN STAT = 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
                         WHEN STAT = 4 THEN 'Hold'
                         WHEN STAT = 5 THEN 'Closed'
                         WHEN STAT = 6 THEN 'Pending(not used)' END AS STATTYPE
                  FROM [my].[dbo].[view]
                                         $where";


    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        $sql1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);
        if ($sql1 === false){
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stno = $row1['STNOFULL'];
            $stname = $row1['STNAMEFULL'];
            $apno = $row1['APNOFULL'];
            $hperprd = $row1['HPERPRD'];
            $hseptyp = $row1['HSEPTYP'];
            echo "<br><h2>".$stno." ".$stname." Permit Number: ".$apno."</h2>";
            echo "<p><strong>Inspection Period:</strong> ".$hperprd." months<br>";
            echo "<strong>System Type:</strong> ".$hseptyp."</p>";
            echo "<hr>";

            $sql2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);
            if ($sql2 === false){
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                if (is_null($row2['COMPDTTM'])){
                    $compdttm = '';
                } else {
                    $compdttm = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row2['COMPDTTM']));
                }
                echo "<h3>Inspection Date:  ".$compdttm."</h3>";
                echo "<p><strong>Inspection Status:</strong> ".$row2['STATTYPE']."<br>";
                if(is_null($row2['DESCRIPT478'])){
                echo "";
                } else {
                    echo "<strong>Code Violation Status:</strong> ".$row2['DESCRIPT478']."<br>";
                }
                echo "<strong>".$row2['FAILED']." ".$row2['DESCRIPT']."</strong></p>";
                echo "<p>".$row2['COMMENTS255']." ".$row2['LOC']." ".$row2['COMMENTSFAILED']."</p>";
                echo "<hr>";
                }
                sqlsrv_free_stmt($sql2);
                sqlsrv_free_stmt($sql1);
        }
```

What would be the best method to go about this?  For, foreach, if/else, while, etc.?

Comment: How would anybody know? We don't have sample data or desired output.

Comment: @SeanLange are you asking for the sql query?

Comment: Well that is part of it. We don't know what your data is or what you want as output. But before you write any more queries you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection and my friend bobby tables loves codes like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your help so far.  I have been reading up on parameterized queries, just trying to make this work first.  I updated my original question with more information - apologies as I've been staring at it for so long I didn't even think about someone from the outside not knowing what our column names actually meant...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the link on how to post the table info. I couldn't get the excel info to line up very well.  I can make my way around an automotive forum pretty well but this is still new - apologies.

Comment: What do you expect as output from your sample data? Post is more like your data. What you have right now as desired output doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: The desired output would be the values from those column names ordered by the `['COMPDTTM']` value. Basically, the user searches their street number and street name and then it displays the data within the page formatted to be readable.  My desired output above just utilizes the column names the value would be coming from.  I would add additional text to the HTML so it's more readable, right now I'm just focusing on the data itself being displayed.

Comment: Well that is clear as mud. It sounds like you are wanting to use a query to handle formatting your data in the presentation layer. Any presentation should be handled in the front end, not directly in the sql.

Comment: I'm not using the sql to present the data, php is doing that just fine.  My issue is with the loop.  Everything in the `while` loop gets displayed.  My issue is if an address has more than one permit.  The second (or third or fourth) permit information is not displayed, but the `while` loop information for those respective permits still displays.

Comment: Perhaps I have not been fully clear either. You do not want or need a loop here. You want to retrieve ALL of your data in a single query. Processing data row by agonizing row (RBAR) is horribly inefficient. You go to the database and grab all the data you need and bring it back to your application. Then your application takes that data and presents it. As such it is still not clear what you want back with the data. Not an explanation of this column and that column. The actual results you expect from the sample data you posted.

Comment: I updated the table and the desired results for how they should display on the webpage.  I hope this makes sense now.  Does this line `$row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);` grab all the data I need and dump it into the array appropriately?  Instead of that line plus my `while` loop?

Comment: My `$row1` variable just fetches one row, thus performing your RBAR.  How do I fetch all the data for a given address at once?

Comment: @SeanLange `while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    foreach ($row1 as $key => $value) {
                        echo "$key => $value <br>";
                    }                    
                }` This returns everything from the search.  I still am unsure on how display the unique permit information once while displaying all the inspection date info.  I'm assuming that since this is in a loop this is still processing the data RBAR as you stated previously...

Comment: Processing the results in the client application is not a huge deal. That is perfectly normal. It is when you have a loop and inside that loop is a new query for each pass. That is when things really slow down. The biggest issue still is that we have no data to work with still. And still nothing representing what you expect from the database. I posted a link 2 days ago that talks about what to post but we haven't seen anything like that.

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the original question with the desired output for what I want to display on the webpage.  I also updated the sample table with the pertinent data that relates to my desired output.  I removed the screenshot of the sample table and followed the link you provided to get that input correctly into the question.  Am I still missing something?

Comment: I guess I missed the sample data. Those field names make want to slit my wrist. And then you have them all concatenated together. This seems like a pretty common thing for output. You have a "group header" and multiple details under it. I can't help you with php, I can't even spell it. Back in the day this type of output was known as control break processing. You order your results by something and only print the new header details when the current row is a new value than the previous row.

Comment: @SeanLange I didn't design the database, the whole thing makes me want to slit my wrist!  Thanks for at least helping me get the question formatted correctly.  I'll see if I can find anything on control break processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made this extremely difficult for no reason.  At some point in the past several days of scouring Google I did something similar, however, I didn't have the `$prevapno = $apno` in the correct location so it never worked.  I created an additional variable `$prevapno` and then added an `if()` statement like so:

```
    if(isset($_GET['search'])){

            $sql1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
            if ($sql1 === false){
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            $prevapno = ""; // created the new variable
            while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $apkey = $row1['APKEYFULL'];
                $stno = $row1['STNOFULL'];
                $stname = $row1['STNAMEFULL'];
                $apno = $row1['APNOFULL'];
                $hperprd = $row1['HPERPRD'];
                $hseptyp = $row1['HSEPTYP'];

                //added this if statement

                if ($apno != $prevapno) {     
                    echo "<br><h2>".$stno." ".$stname." Permit Number: ".$apno."</h2>";
                    echo "<p><strong>Inspection Period:</strong> ".$hperprd." months<br>";
                    echo "<strong>System Type:</strong> ".$hseptyp."</p>";
                    echo "<hr>";
                }
                $prevapno = $apno; //set the new variable to compare here

                if (is_null($row1['COMPDTTM'])){
                    $compdttm = '';
                } else {
                    $compdttm = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row1['COMPDTTM']));
                }
                echo "<h3>Inspection Date:  ".$compdttm."</h3>";
                echo "<p><strong>Inspection Status:</strong> ".$row1['STATTYPE']."<br>";
                if(is_null($row1['DESCRIPT478'])){
                    echo "";
                } else {
                    echo "<strong>Code Violation Status:</strong> ".$row1['DESCRIPT478']."<br>";
                }
                echo "<strong>".$row1['FAILED']." ".$row1['DESCRIPT']."</strong></p>";
                echo "<p>".$row1['COMMENTS255']." ".$row1['LOC']." ".$row1['COMMENTSFAILED']."</p>";
                Echo "<hr>";

            }
        }
```